# Is it a good idea to use a list of *bufio.Scanner for files to be read later in golang?

Tags: go

I have a list of delimited files to be read after I obtained their path. Instead of saving path as a string, I'm wondering can I simply store a list of *bufio.Scanner so those will be much easier to be read later (and code will be cleaner too)? Here is a quick example:

```
func main(){
    scannerList := read(filenameList)
    dowork(scannerList)
}

func read(filenameList []string) (scannerList []*bufio.Scanner){
    for _, filename := range filenameList{
        op, _ := os.Open(filename)
        defer op.Close()
        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(op)
        scannerList = append(scannerList, scanner)
    }
    return
}

func dowork(scannerList []*bufio.Scanner){
    for _, scanner := range scannerList{
        for scanner.Scan(){
            //read stuff
        }
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

My code similar to above example compiles, but I don't know if this is recommended (or works). Any comments? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Scanner` is a complicated structure, and one that embeds a buffer.  The buffer can grow dynamically (depending on what the `scan` function requests) up to 64kB (`MaxScanTokenSize`).

So in general it is not a good idea to keep redundant `Scanner`s around, as the buffers cannot be released until the `Scanner`s are discarded.  But perhaps a few extra kilobytes of memory don't matter much in your case.

Comment: May I know if scanner has the information about op (from os.Open)? In other words, is the defer op.Close() triggered inside function read() or inside function dowork() ? Thanks!

Comment: This has nothing to do with the scanner - you call `Close` in `read`, so `Close` is called in `read`.